# Regex: Matching everything expect a given expression (not char)?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm using SED to remove C-Style comments.

Here is the command I'm using:

sed s:[/][*].*[*][/]::g

There 2 cases I can't figure out:

First:

```
int x /* comment */ = 1; /* comment */
```

output:
    int x

Second: multi-line comment

```
/* first line 
   second line */
```

Output:

```
/* first line
   second line */
```

The first problem is with the .* in the middle as the pattern matching is greedy and once the first "/*" is matches [/][*], the inner comment expression match .* and the ending comment expression matches the ending the [*][/].

Now the problem with the second is "." doesn't match new line character but if i put a new line character the following thing happens.

input:

```
int x;
/* comment */
x = 1;
/* comment */
```

output:

```
int x;
```

Can some tell me how to make closing tags are matched not consumed by .* or [\s\S]*?

Comment: Usually the right syntax for this is: .*?

Comment: int x /* comment */ = 1; /* comment */  I think whoever writes code like this need to be executed on the spot..

Comment: All T.A. should be executed regardless of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one Regex I could come up with : `\/\*(.*?)\*\/`

Input :

```
`int x /* comment */ = 1; /* comment */ 
/* first line 
   second line */
int x;
/* comment */
x = 1;
/* comment */`
```

Output is:

```
$matches Array:
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => /* comment */
            [1] => /* comment */
            [2] => /* first line second line */
            [3] => /* comment */
            [4] => /* comment */
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] =>  comment 
            [1] =>  comment 
            [2] =>  first line second line 
            [3] =>  comment 
            [4] =>  comment 
        )

)
```

Comment: And now this one: `printf(" /* "); /* oh no... */` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with `python`, see here: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/11/remove-c-comments-python/

Actually you can do that with `sed` as well, but, well, see here: http://sed.sourceforge.net/grabbag/scripts/remccoms3.sed

And here are some `perl` solutions: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#How-do-I-use-a-regular-expression-to-strip-C-style-comments-from-a-file%3f

HTH

Answer (score 0):

awk:

```
awk -F"\033" -v RS="\034" '{gsub("\*\/","\034");gsub(/\/\*[^\034]*\034/,"");print}' input.c
```